# Why does setting a property on an enumerated object not work?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I know a lot about C# but this one is stumping me and Google isn't helping.

I have an IEnumerable range of objects.  I want to set a property on the first one.  I do so, but when I enumerate over the range of objects after the modification, I don't see my change.

Here's a good example of the problem:

```
    public static void GenericCollectionModifier()
    {
        // 1, 2, 3, 4... 10
        var range = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

        // Convert range into SubItem classes
        var items = range.Select(i => new SubItem() {Name = "foo", MagicNumber = i});

        Write(items);  // Expect to output 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

        // Make a change
        items.First().MagicNumber = 42;

        Write(items);  // Expect to output 42,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
        // Actual output: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
    }

    public static void Write(IEnumerable<SubItem> items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", items.Select(item => item.MagicNumber.ToString()).ToArray()));
    }

    public class SubItem
    {
       public string Name;
       public int MagicNumber;
    }
```

What aspect of C# stops my "MagicNumber = 42" change from being output?  Is there a way I can get my change to "stick" without doing some funky converting to List<> or array?

Thanks!
-Mike

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call First() it enumerates over the result of this bit of code:

```
Select(i => new SubItem() {Name = "foo", MagicNumber = i});
```

Note that the Select is a lazy enumerator, meaning that it only does the select when you ask for an item from it (and does it *every* time you ask it). The results are not stored anywhere, so when you call items.First() you get a new `SubItem` instance. When you then pass items to Write, it gets a whole bunch of new `SubItem` instances - not the one you got before.

If you want to store the result of your select and modify it, you need to do something like:

```
var items = range.Select(i => new SubItem() {Name = "foo", MagicNumber = i}).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes +1. For `items` as defined in the original question, each time `items` is iterated, new `SubItem` instances are created. And `.First()` iterates it once, and `Write` iterates it a second time. Another consequence of this is that (with `items` still as in the original question) `items.First() == items.First()` evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect something going in the background. Most likely due to the fact the IEnumerables can only be iterated once.

Does it work if you add a 'ToList()' after the call to Select() when assigning to 'items'?

Comment: Yes, if I convert it to a List it works as expected.  I'm hoping to avoid that though.

Comment: IEnumerables cannot only be iterated once. They are lazy evaluating so that each time you iterate you may get a different result. Adding ToList() will fix the problem, however.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that items.First() passes a copy of SubItem to your instead of the reference, so when you set it the change isn't carried through.

I have to assume it has something to do with IQueryable only being able to be iterated once.  You may want to try changing this:

```
// Convert range into SubItem classes
var items = range.Select(i => new SubItem() {Name = "foo", MagicNumber = i});
```

to

```
// Convert range into SubItem classes
var items = range.Select(i => new SubItem() {Name = "foo", MagicNumber = i}).ToList();
```

And see if there are any different results.

Answer (score 0):

You can't/shouldn't modify a collection through an enumerator.  I'm surprised this doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: The collection isn't being modified, the data inside an item is

Answer (score 0):

.First() is a method, not a property.  It returns a new instance of the object in the first position of your Enumerable.

Comment: It does not return a copy, it returns the actual object